# Is there Any Way To Compact Repetitious Color setting?

Tags: java, android

As you know We can Use `int a,b,c=3;` instead of:

```
int a;
int b;
int c=3;
```

I use a lot of code like following. For Example To Change View or Other Setting. And it waste a lot of my time. Is there any way to make it easier?

```
    //<editor-fold desc="Not Dark Mode">
    Button Save=findViewById(R.id.Setting_Save_BTN);
    Button Back=findViewById(R.id.Setting_Back_BTN);
    Button Instruction=findViewById(R.id.Setting_Instruction_BTN);
    TextView Title=findViewById(R.id.Setting_Title_TXT);
    TextView Display=findViewById(R.id.Setting_Display_TXT);
    TextView Progress=findViewById(R.id.Setting_Progress_Bar_TXT);
    TextView Relaps=findViewById(R.id.Setting_Relaps_TXT);
    TextView Lang=findViewById(R.id.Setting_Language_TXT);

    findViewById(R.id.Setting_Layout).setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    Phone_Language.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    Persian.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    Arabic.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    English.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    Spanish.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    Hindi.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    Malay.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    Portuguese.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    Russian.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    Chinese.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    .
    .
    .
    OnePhase.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    ThreePhase.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    Save.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    Back.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    Relaps.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    Lang.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    //</editor-fold>
```

I'll be grateful if you answer me...

Comment: Use butterknife BindViews and loop over them

Comment: Well buddy do some research before asking. Butterknife, kotlin are fine examples of it. Just google "Dependency injections android".

Comment: neither butterknife nor kotlin classifies as dependency injection

Comment: Thanks But I couldn't find Any thing that solve my problem. Maybe becouse  I don't understand English Very well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the repetition by using a loop.

```
TextView[] makeBlack = new TextView [] {
    Persian, Arabic, English, Spanish,
    Hindi, Malay // add the rest
};
for (TextView view: makeBlack) {
    view.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
}
```

Comment: It Really Works. Thank you.